# WP_Comment_Query with 5 top level comments per page?

Tags: comments, wp-comment-query

I'm trying to replicate the option in WordPress's settings page that says:

> [x] Break comments into pages with ((5)) top level comments per page and the ((first)) page displayed by default

Right now I have the following comment query, but it only displays 5 comments, also counting the replies.

The behavior I want is 5 top-level comments, and all the replies those top-level comments might have. How do I achieve this?

### Current Code

```
$args = array(
    'post_id' => $post_id,
    'type' => 'comment',
    'status' => 'approve',
    
    'number' => 5,
    'hierarchical' => 'threaded'
);

$comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
$comments = $comments_query->query($args);
```

### Output

Total of 5 comments

> Comment 1
>
> - Reply to comment 1
> - Reply to comment 1
>
> Comment 2
>
> Comment 3

### Desired Output

5 top-level comments and all their replies

> Comment 1
>
> - Reply to comment 1
> - Reply to comment 1
>
> Comment 2
>
> Comment 3
>
> - Reply to comment 3
> - Reply to comment 3
> - Reply to comment 3
>
> Comment 4
>
> Comment 5
>
> - Reply to comment 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Updated*

The `hierarchical` parameter controls whether to include comment descendants in the comments results.

From the [inline docs](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-includes/class-wp-comment-query.php#L246) we have that it accepts the following values:

> - `'threaded'` returns a tree, with each comment's children stored in a `children` property on the `WP_Comment` object.
> - `'flat'` returns a flat array of found comments plus their children.
> - `false` to leave out descendants.

It also says that

> The parameter is ignored (forced to `false`) when `$fields` is 'ids'
>   or 'counts'.

Both the `'threaded'` and `'flat'` options makes use of the [`WP_Comment_Query::fill_descendants()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_comment_query/fill_descendants/) method:

> Instead of calling `get_children()` separately on each child comment, we
>   do a single set of queries to fetch the descendant trees for all
>   matched top-level comments.

but the threaded option has [additional snippet](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-includes/class-wp-comment-query.php#L1035) that uses the `add_child()` method of the `WP_Comment` object to construct the `children` property.

---

As @Swen mentioned in comments, one should use the `'threaded'` option.

It looks like the `true` value would in fact give the same as the `'flat'` option.

Comment: `WP_Comment_Query::fill_descendants()` looks great! But I'm unsure how to use it... Could you provide an example?

Comment: Also note that `'hierarchical' => true` is invalid and it should be `'hierarchical => 'threaded'`.